# Prevent local WordPress from deleting Plugins via Symlink

Tags: wordpress, symbolic-link, symlink

I run a local web server for developing plugins. My plugins reside in git repositories and I create symlinks to link them to the WordPress installations plugin folder.

Sometimes it happens that I accidentially use the wrong browser tab and delete one of the plugins which causes WordPress to remove the data completely from my disk and I'd like to prevent hat somehow.

Could I for example just remove the write access on the symlink and then WordPress could not delete the plugins anymore?

Comment: Your web server should not have write access to WordPress at all.

Comment: What better way do you suggest? WordPress needs write access to its own folder structure so I can install/uninstall 3rd party plugins and themes. I want to stop WordPress from being able to delete plugins which I linked from another location on my hdd to WordPress plugin folder via symlinks. (e. g. in "~/Sites/wordpress/wp-content/plugins" I create a symlink using "ln -s ~/Documents/wordpress/plugins/my-plugin")

Comment: I use wp-cli in production. WordPress can only write to the uploads folder.